# STRQSH vs start.sh difference

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ibm-midrange

I'm on the IBM i v7r3

When I run a command/program interactively in Qshell it runs successfully.  But when I try to run this in start.sh it fails with Command serve not found.

I start an interactive Qshell session.

```
STRQSH
$ cd node/vlegacireactjs
$ serve -s build -l 8010
```

The above starts a react server which I confirm is reachable when I point my browser at port 8010.
I am trying to run a program that will start the server in batch.

```
SBMJOB CMD(QSH CMD('/home/RROGERSON/node/vlegacireactjs/start.sh')) +
       JOB(NODE_REACT) JOBQ(QS36EVOKE) CPYENVVAR(*YES)
```

And then start.sh contains

```
#1/usr/bin/sh
cd /home/RROGERSON/node/vlegacireactjs
serve -s build -l 8010
```

The job NODE_REACT fails (as seen in the QPRINT spool file) with Command serve not found .

Does anyone know what I have to add to start.sh to get this to run?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: What do your profile scripts look like? Look at both `/etc/profile` and `/home/RROGERSON/.profile`. Both of these run when you call qsh interactively, but not if you call qsh in batch.

Comment: If one of the profile files creates an `ENV` variable, also show us the contents of the file it points at. That is also run when ash is called interactively, but not when called in batch.

Answer (score 1):

I should have paid more attention to the error. It was telling me the command serve was not found.
So I changed to

```
/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/nodejs10/bin/serve -s build -l 8010
```

and the command is found.  The module serve was installed globally.

Thanks for the suggestion Mark